# TradingView charting Library :How to add cryptocurrency exchange symbols in chart?

Tags: cryptocurrency, tradingview-api

I am populating tradingView chart using charting library but it populates for selective symbols.
It shows very few exchanges and some symbols.
However I want to populate charts for all the cryptocurrency exchanges/symbols.
How can I add exchange and its symbols? Please refer img to get the exact issuse.
Also I can not see the pine editor option in the chart. How can I get the pine editor?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to plot multiple crypto symbols in one chart, or multiple charts each with its own symbol? Btw your img attachment is not showing.